# Improving copper contact and preventing oxidation

Tags: metal, conductivity

I have a model railway in which I use pure copper on the tracks and in the engine to power the train with electricity.

Is there any solution to prevent the copper surfaces from corrosion, and maybe improve the conductivity?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not tried them *DeoxIT* products claim to do what you want, available as [liquid](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003D8EA7A) and [spray](http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/g5s-6/deoxit-r-gold-5-oz/1.html).

If anyone has used these, please add a comment as to effectiveness.

Comment: It seems promising, but 7USD for 2ml just doen't worth it...